# How to include dynamic properties in path name inside dom-repeat?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to bind the state of a checkbox to a specific nested subproperty of `hostProperty`. The checkboxes are generated inside a nested "dom-repeat" template (iterating through `innerObj` per `outerObj`), and the desired subproperty of `hostProperty` is relative to subproperties of the other objects, i.e. it is of the form `hostProperty[outerObj.name][innerObj.name]`.

I have been unable to figure out the correct path name for the subproperty.

I have tried the following and all have failed:
- `hostProperty.outerObj.name.innerObj.name` (likely looks for `hostProperty.outerObj.name` which is undefined)
- `['hostProperty', outerObj.name, innerObj.name]`  (based on the [documentation for specifying paths](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#specifying-paths))
- `hostProperty[outerObj.name][innerObj.name]`
- `hostProperty.outerObj['name'].innerObj['name']`

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[outerObj_arr]]" as="outerObj">
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">[[outerObj.name]]</th>                    
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[innerObj_arr]]" as="innerObj">
            <!-- broken path name below -->
            <td><paper-checkbox checked="[[hostProperty.outerObj.name.innerObj.name]]"></paper-checkbox></td>
        </template>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is impossible from the html template.
To get this working, you need to use a helper method, eg:

```
<td><paper-checkbox checked="[[_getChecked(hostProperty, outerObj.name, innerObj.name)]]"></paper-checkbox></td>
```

And then in js:

```
_getChecked(list, key1, key2) {
  return list[key1][key2];
}
```

Comment: Perhaps so. Unfortunately this helper method has the entire `hostProperty` object as a dependency, so for each observable change to `hostProperty` this method would be called for _every_ checkbox. Is there a way for the method to depend on a different subproperty of `hostProperty` for each checkbox?